# How to create and send data packets in C++

Tags: c++, sockets

I want to send the following data as packet to a socket using C++, all in one packet:

```
  fixed header:   { 0xe1,0xe2}          
   data1(int) :   {0x1e,0x25,0x71,0x80}               
   data2(int):    {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x23}
```

What would the code typically look like to create and send the packet containing all this data with Initial value ?

Comment: For all things network related see [**Beej's Guide to Network Programming**](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/). It is an excellent reference/tutorial for network programming.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin ok tnx

Comment: Why not just using `send(socket, buffer, size, flags)`? Do you have any special needs?